# Is it possible for the US to borrow money from other countries, after the shutdown?

Tags: united-states, economy, government-shutdown

After the government shutdown and the startle of debt default, is it possible for the US government to issue bonds, and borrow money from other countries?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the US has already issued more bonds, which have been bought both by foreign and domestic investors. The whole point of avoiding a default was that people would still have confidence in the US dollar. After all, in the end the US did pay its debts, and it's still the largest and one of the safest economies in the world.

Comment: Totally agree with the facts you listed. If I can ask a further question just from curiosity, is there any chance that US dollar may have a "sudden death" in the future? Say, another day in the future, after another threatening of default and thus cause fundings run out of US?

Comment: This isn't the place to ask about speculation I'm afraid. We try to stick to known facts.